# AWS S3 file upload access denied in php codeigniter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

unable to upload files to aws s3 bucket shows "
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: User Warning

Message: S3::putObject(): [AccessDenied] Access Denied

Filename: libraries/S3.php"

Comment: You have to provide more details? Any bucket policies? How do you access the object? Which user/role permissions?

Comment: AmazonS3FullAccess on  bucket policies/accesing by specifying the access_key,secret_key,bucket_name,s3_url,foldername etc /root user having all permissions

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this problem-

1. If your Bucket permission "Bucket and object not public"
   First, you need to change the permission in AWS S3
   Go to Bucket->permission->edit

Uncheck

```
- Block new public ACLs and uploading public object
- Remove public access granted through public ACLs
```

Now try to upload, I hope it will work.

2. Use "S3::ACL_PRIVATE" in your putObjectFile function parameter at the time of upload file. ACL_PRIVATE and other keys are declared in the s3.php library file.

   ```
   $saved = $this->s3->putObjectFile($file_path,
            $this->bucket_name,
            $this->folder_name.$s3_file,
            S3::ACL_PRIVATE,
            array(),
            $mime_type);
   ```

Now try to upload.